# Use itertools for nested loop in python 3.9

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools

I was wondering if it is possible to improve nested loops when the second one depends on the first one like the code below:

```py
data = [
    [{'return_code': 0, 'count': 259}, {'return_code': 2, 'count': 1}],
    [{'return_code': 1, 'count': 228}],
    []
]

for elt in filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, data):
    for e in filter(lambda x: "return_code" in x, elt):
        do_something()
        do_something_else()
```

I've heard of `itertools.product` for nested independent loops but I can't seem to find a case that fits my needs.

Is there a more pythonic way to handle such nested loops?

Comment: The Pythonic way is probably to use neither ``filter``+``lambda``, nor ``itertools``, but simply a nested ``if`` statement. Either way, can you give a criteria what you consider to "improve" the code?

Comment: In this exact case you can simply check for `"return_code" in x for x in data`, because if the key exists, the dict isn't empty, so `len(x)` is superfluous.

Comment: btw your `filter()` in the first loop is superfluous. You just need: `for elt in data:`

Comment: Well, I'm trying to simplify a code that has a lot of nested loops of this style. Sometimes going up to 4 or 5 levels and the indentation becomes problematic for readability.
Also many conditions are already present and the use of `filter` helps me to reduce this indentation but it is not enough.
Tools like `radon` compute a cyclomatic complexity at F on most functions, so I try to reduce it to a score of A.

Comment: ```[[print(e) for e in elt] for elt in data]``` ... however as others, your filter is not doing anything useful for your example.

Comment: If you have "4 or 5 levels" of indentation and it is a problem, consider to move code *out* to a function. Cramming this much complexity into a single expression will only reduce indentation, not complexity – and likely at the *cost* of readability.

Comment: I agree with MisterMiyagi. It would also be to your benefit to show us an example code that more closely represents your case, because the current one was trivial. It also sounds this is an appropriate question for [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if your code already works and you just want to improve some aspects of it. But [don't cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).